# How to Convert string to xml gregorian calendar date java

Tags: java, string, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I am trying to convert String to gregoriancalendar date, it unable to convert. because, the string has different format. like '**2015-05-22T16:28:40.317-04:00**'. I have seen some of the other examples, but they are not in this time format.

I am using something like below:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
         cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-SS:zz").parse(sampleDate));
         XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar( cal);
```

I even tried like this too:

```
gregory.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(sampleDate));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doc, you will see that there's no `T` in the format pattern. In order to escape non-pattern characters, wrap them around single quotes `'` as shown in this example (taken from the docs):

```
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" -> 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
```

I think the proper format should be this:

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX";
//                         ^-^-----check these
// don't pay attention to the smiley generated above, they're arrows ;)
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
     cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(sampleDate));
     XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar( cal);
```

Comment: Or use Java 8, `ZonedDateTime` and standard ISO formatting

Comment: @Luiggi: getting error as unparsable date                       java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-07-19T00:00:00-04:00"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java_text_DateFormat$parse.call(Unknown Source)

Comment: @David fixed. Please test it back.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: have tried the updated one too, but same exception. It looks simple but I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: I've tested it and worked with no problems. Looks like you're prodiving a wrong sample data in your question.

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-12-23T00:00:00-05:00" SO the date format is there. DO not know why.

Comment: Your last example doesn't contain milliseconds, that's why it fails.

Comment: For the last format I have used "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-SS:zz" format.  Is there any way where, we can convert discarding seconds and milli seconds. what even the input date format is.

Comment: @David the last one should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX". The `-05:00` is the time zone, those are not milliseconds. If you don't know which format to apply, use multiple `SimpleDateFormat` instances and try one after another until you get your desired date.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2015-05-22T16:28:40.317-04:00");
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-SS:zz");
      //dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone());
      Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(inputDatetime);

      GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
      c.setTime(inputDate);

      XMLGregorianCalendar outputDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);

      return outputDate;

    } catch (ParseException | DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
      log.error("exception: {}", e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
```